# Visual Studio Code access Git on local NAS

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, synology

I run a Git server on a Synology NAS.  Using Visual Studio Code. I'd like to save my work to a local repo on the NAS.  I've looked into some extensions including [GitHub Repositories](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github.remotehub) and others.  Each seems to want to authenticate to GitHub.

I need a solution that will allow me to commit my changes to my local Git server while working within Visual Studio code.  Does such a solution exist?

**UPDATE: July 22**

I'm not sure the Git Extension is compatible with my Synology NAS.  I was able to set up access using Tortoisegit.  However, when I tried accessing the git server from within VSCODE, I get:

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused why using git on it's own doesn't work? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: Why not just create a bare repo on a share on the NAS, then just push your changes to it from your local working copy?  Basically, use the NAS-side repo as a remote.  I've been doing my projects this way, and it works well within VSCode.  It allows me to use the NAS repo from multiple computers as needed.  No extra extensions needed.

Comment: ^ What they said, plus: Synology has a Git binary for its NAS line, which should streamline the setup and management process. Point VSCode at that and you're basically done.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will dig deeper and post what I end up with.